# findAllByAttributes not returning any value in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am passing following array in findAllByAttributes() method in my Yii Web App.

```
$fileArr= Array
(
    [0] => 790c83
    [1] => 402faf
    [2] => 646209
    [3] => 9332c5
)

$files = File::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('code' => $fileArr));
        print_r($fileArr);
        exit;
```

and when I am trying to print this its returning blank. I also tried by converting an array into string by using implode function and passed it into `findAllByAttributes()` method but still its not working. How can I achieve this in yii?

Comment: use addInCondition and check

Comment: What is the result of a `findAll()` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('code', $fileArr);
$files = File::model()->findAll($criteria);
print_r($files);
exit;
```

Comment: Do you have any default scopes defined? What is the actual query that is being executed?